# Maveryx vs FitNesse vs Robot for desktop GUI testing on Mac, Windows and Linux

Tags: user-interface, testing, cross-platform, automated-tests, jruby

Please compare and contrast the suitability of **at least two** of these tools for automated testing of GUI applications on Mac OS X, Windows and Linux.

- [FitNesse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FitNesse)
- [Maveryx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maveryx)
- [Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)

The applications under test will likely be written using JRuby and Swing, in case that's a factor in your appraisal.

**Brownie points for discussing all three tools in your answer :)**

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that Robot and FitNesse are frameworks for managing your test cases, but do not actually include the driver for automating the target GUI. You would still need to integrate either of these with an actual GUI automation tool for the actual execution of button clicks, etc...

Comment: @Tom, if you're right, that's going to complicate my life a bit. I'm not ready to start using any of the three tools I mentioned just yet, but posted the question by way of a recce, so this is the kind of info I want to know. By all means shine further light on the matter :)

Answer (score 5):

FitNesse requires that you set up a server, and all of the tests are written via web pages served by that server. It has the advantage that anyone can create, run or examine your test cases. Because of this, it is arguably a bit more friendly toward product specialists

Robot, on the other hand, is more of a command line tool. It has the advantage that you can edit test cases with the editor of your choice because the supported test formats are all plain text (tab-separated, html, rst). There is a functional (but buggy, as of this writing) IDE (RIDE) you can use on windows, linux and OSX. An advantage of this format is that you can check the test cases in to the same repository as the code, and it is easily integrated with a CI server such as Jenkins. Because of this, robot is arguably a bit more friendly toward technical types (software and test developers).

Both have roughly the same limitations with respect to testing desktop, swing-based GUIs. Both have the ability to hook into the application under test, but desktop GUI testing is inherently difficult.

Comment: Upvoted for a VERY helpful answer, thanks. Do you have any experience with Maveryx?

Comment: @sampabiokuper: no, I do not have any experience with maveryx